# Google Places seo?

Tags: google, google-search, local-seo, google-places

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What determines the order of results for Google Places?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/11772/what-determines-the-order-of-results-for-google-places)

I'm familiar with SEO and getting higher Google listings but for allot of services Google has recently been making there search results (were applicable) much more location orientated..

for instance searching for a "accountant in london" or "accountancy firm london" will through return the first half of page 1 as Google places listings, then under about 6 of these you will get your normal search results so someone who used to rank #1 on page 1 now will rank effectively #7.

What I was wandering is that I cant see any reasons as to why the company that rank high in the places results get there, often they are not high up in the search results.

Is there a way to optimise on or offsite to rise up the Google places listings in your city?